# How to combine two df with two different timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two different dfs each with a timestamp. One is collecting data every minute, the other just in case of a change, so sometimes every second, sometimes a couple hours in between two rows. How can I append the columns of df2 to df1 so the timestamp would be the same? df2 would show the same value in each row (so each minute) until something changes (so ffill the NaN's). It's okay to loose some information through that, it's more important to put the dfs together. I'm still a beginner so help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

At the moment it looks like this:

```
In[10]: df1
Out[10]: 
timestamp, X, Y, Z
2018-12-15 08:00:00, 134, 7, 276
2018-12-15 08:01:00, 130, 7, 278
2018-12-15 08:02:00, 136, 8, 291

In[11]: df2
Out[11]: 
timestamp, A, B, C
2018-12-15 07:34:36, 1, 44, 21
2018-12-15 08:00:46, NaN, 50, 20
2018-12-15 08:00:52, 0, NaN, 30
```

It's supposed to look like this:

```
In[12]: df
Out[12]:
timestamp, X, Y, Z, A, B, C
2018-12-15 08:00:00, 134, 7, 276, 1, 44, 21
2018-12-15 08:01:00, 130, 7, 278, 0, 50, 30
2018-12-15 08:02:00, 136, 8, 291, 0, 50, 30
```

Comment: Why A B C values are 0, 50, 30 in the two last rows of the joined dataframe? According to your original data, should be 0. Those values should be summed togheter in the 08:00:00 bin.

Comment: @Valentino I want to keep the old values as long as nothing changes, because df2 is from sensors that only show numbers when there's a change. I don't want to sum them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) which will merge on closest *match*:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='timestamp')

            timestamp    X   Y    Z   A     B   C
0 2018-12-15 08:00:00  134   7  276   1    44  21
1 2018-12-15 08:01:00  130   7  278   0   NaN  30
2 2018-12-15 08:02:00  136   8  291   0   NaN  30
```

Note if your `timestamp` columns are not in `datetime` format, first convert them to the correct format using [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'])
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'])
```

If you want to fill the `NaN` use:

```
df3 = df3.ffill()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I get the following error: "Argument 'right_values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got DatetimeArray)". How can I deal with that?

Comment: Convert both `datetime` column to datetime, see my **note** line.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). First, be sure that `'timestamp'` is of type datetime and set it as the index of your dataframes.

```
df1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'])
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'])
```

This to make them of datetime type

```
df1.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
```

This to set them as index.

Then you just need to resample `df2` to bin of 1 minute:

```
rsdf2 = df2.resample('1T').sum()
```

The `sum()` method will sums togheter values in the same bin, and put 0 in empty bins. You can use different functions of course, depending on your needs. `.mean()` for example if you want the mean value instead of the sum.

Now depends on how do you want to join them. The function is [pandas.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).
You want to keep all indexes? Use:

```
pd.concat([df1, rsdf2], axis=1)
```

It will fill with NaN rows absent in one of the dataframe.

You want to keep common indexes only? Use:

```
pd.concat([df1, rsdf2], axis=1, join='inner')
```

You want to keep the exact indexes of the first dataframe? Use:

```
pd.concat([df1, rsdf2], axis=1, join_axes=[df1.index])
```

For example, this last one, using your sample dataframes, will give:

```
                       X  Y    Z    A     B     C
timestamp                                        
2018-12-15 08:00:00  134  7  276  0.0  50.0  50.0
2018-12-15 08:01:00  130  7  278  NaN   NaN   NaN
2018-12-15 08:02:00  136  8  291  NaN   NaN   NaN
```